# Given 10 different English books, six different French books, and four different German books

Tags: combinatorics

Given 10 different English books, six different French books, and four different German books, How many ways are there to make a row of three books in which exactly one language is missing (the order of the three books makes a difference)?

to solve this i first broke it down into cases of the excluded language. Doing that i get $2^3$ for each case, then i would sum up the 3 cases or in this scenario: $(3)2^3$. i know i have to be missing something when it comes to the amounts of each book, but i can't figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

If there are e.g. no German books then $2$ English books and $1$ French book is an option and $1$ English book and $2$ French books is an option.

That gives $\binom{10}2\binom61+\binom{10}1\binom62$ possibilities for selecting $3$ books.

There are $3!=6$ ways to order the selected books.

Answer (score 1):

You need two books from one language, and one of another. Say you have n books of the first language, and m of the second one. You pick one book of the first language in n ways and put it on the left. You pick another book of the first language in (n-1) ways and put it on the right. You take one of m books of the second language and either put it to the left, or to the right, or between the other two books. That's 3n(n-1)m ways.

The total is 3*10*9*6 + 3*10*9*4 + 3*6*5*10 + 3*6*5*4 + 3*4*3*10 + 3*4*3*6 = 3*90*10 + 3*30*14 + 3*12*16.